# How to solve segmentation error in C

Tags: c, gcc

So this is the code to print out a vertical histogram for a given set of data.
The data here is in a file "H.in" which is used to import input while using scanf. An example input would be:

```
29
6 3 8 6 7 4 8 9 2 10 4 9 5 7 4 8 6 7 2 10 4 1 8 3 6 3 6 9 4
```

where 29 is the number of numbers for the graph and the rest is the data which needs to be converted to frequencies.
to check the program save the numbers and then provide this as an input to the file.

Basically when i execute it i get a segmentation error.
Now what I understand is that it is caused due to free floating points or error in array dimension... I tried to search and resolve the problem but i failed as i failed to locate the error..

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
//somewhere there is a segmentation fault. 
int *readGrades(int num) {
  int q;
  int *grades[num];
  for (q=0;q<num;q++){
      scanf("%d",grades[q]);//this is taking input for each element and storing it
      }

  return *grades;
}

int arrayMax(int arr[]) {
  int i, max = arr[0];
  for (i=0; i < 9; i++) {
       if (arr[i] > max) {
           max = arr[i];
              }
          }
    return max;
  }

void printHistogram(int freq[10], int *max)/*maxneeds to be added here?*/ {
int x,y, maxi;
maxi = *max;
for(x=0;x<maxi;x++){
  for(y=0;y<10;y++){
      if (freq[y] >= maxi){
          printf("* ");
          }
      else{
          printf(". ");
          }
       }
      printf("\n");
  }
printf("1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 \n");
}

void computeFrequencies(int *grades[]) {
int a;
int freq[10]={0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};

for(a=0;a<(sizeof(*grades)/sizeof(*grades[0]));a++){
switch(*grades[a]){
  case 1:
  freq[0]= freq[0]+1;
    break;
  case 2:
  freq[1]= freq[1]+1;
    break;
  case 3:
  freq[2]= freq[2]+1;
    break;
  case 4:
  freq[3]= freq[3]+1;
    break;
  case 5:
  freq[4]= freq[4]+1;
    break;
  case 6:
  freq[5]= freq[5]+1;
    break;
  case 7:
  freq[6]= freq[6]+1;
    break;
  case 8:
  freq[7]= freq[7]+1;
    break;
  case 9:
  freq[8]= freq[8]+1;
    break;
  case 10:
  freq[9]= freq[9]+1;
    break;
   }
}
int *u;
*u = arrayMax(freq);
printHistogram(freq, *(&u));
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
 int *grades;
 int num;
 scanf("%d",&num);/* this is the number of numbers*/
 grades = readGrades(num);
 computeFrequencies(&grades);
 return 0;
 }
```

Comment: My guess: `scanf("%d",grades[q]);` -> it should be the address of the q'th element, i.e. `scanf("%d",&(grades[q]));`. However, you could use a debugger to identify the line at which the segmentation fault is raised.

Comment: Compile with all warnings and debug info (`gcc -Wall -g`). Then learn how to **use the debugger** (`gdb`)

Comment: @isedev I think you are close, `grades` is a two dimensional array, but while the first dimension is allocated the second is not, so `scanf` is reading into an unallocated pointer.

Comment: I agree with @BasileStarynkevitch.  There are other problems with your code beside the seg fault.  For example, you cannot return `grades[]` in the `readGrades()` as it is a local variable.

Comment: @isedev: I did that and i get this:
histogram.c:8:4: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int *’, but argument 2 has type ‘int **’ [-Wformat]

Comment: @Ridhay: so you have to fix your source till you get no warnings. The declaration of `grades` inside `readGrades` is very wrong.

Comment: @namfuak well spotted, missed that... you've probably nailed it.

Comment: @Basile - It gives me segmentation fault.. after i do run and backtrace..

Comment: And the switch is horrible -- you are a programmer, not a typist, so spot the pattern and *program*.

Comment: Good, so continue to improve your debugging skills and your knowledge of C. Don't expect us to do your homework. You have a lot to read, to learn, to experiment.

Comment: @Ridhay You should follow Basile's advice on going through with a debugger, but you should also note that using a non-constant int to initialize a constant size array, as you do with `grades[num]`, is not C standard and is only allowed on GCC through an extension, so it may not be portable to other compilers.  You can kill two birds with one stone (making your code portable and not returning a local variable) by allocating your `grades` array using [`malloc`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_malloc.htm)

Comment: @Namfuak I'm still pretty new to pointers.. how did that turn into a 2D array? :/

Comment: Using a barebones gdb needs some getting used to (I couldn't do it out of the box). The easiest solution is probably to use Visual studio express on windows (or a windows VM...). But any linux GUI should have a visual debugger. Any recommendations out there?

Comment: @Namfuak 
Okay, I'll update this once I'm done with debugging and editing of the code. 
Thank you!

Comment: GDB has a nice `help` command.

Comment: An array of constant size (compile time constant size to be standards compliant, IE `grades[5]` or `static int i = 5; grades[i]`) is already an `int*`, so adding `int*` to the front makes it a 2-dimensional array (an array pointing to pointers).  `int grades[5]` would be a pointer to a fixed size array of `int` variables.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Yeah I just found that. Never used it before. Thanks! :D lets see how this goes..

Comment: @Namfuak OH! I see what you mean. Thank you for explaining. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your function

```
computeFrequencies(int *grades[])
```

the line

```
for(a=0;a<(sizeof(*grades)/sizeof(*grades[0]));a++){
```

will not do what you think it will do, sizeof(*grades) gives you the size of an int ptr since *grades[] will decay into a int** pointer.

Instead pass the size of your array as a separate argument

```
computeFrequencies(int *grades[], size_t gradeArraySize)
```

more seriously though this function is returning the address of a local variable:

```
int *readGrades(int num) 
{
  int q;
  int *grades[num];
  for (q=0;q<num;q++){
      scanf("%d",grades[q]);//this is taking input for each element and storing it
      }

  return *grades;
}
```

to return the array you need to typically allocate memory and return a pointer to it or pass the memory where to to store the values as an argument with some max size or allocate then reallocate if the number of values is larger than what fits into the memory block.

In your case the simplest would be to just give a max size (example, not compiled)

```
size_t readGrades(size_t maxgrades, int *grades) 
{
  // use fgets to read from the keyboard
  int actualSize = 0;
  char buffer[128];
  if (fgets( buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin ) != NULL && actualSize < maxgrades)
  {
    for (char* p = strtok(buffer, " "); p != NULL; p = strtok(NULL, " ")
    {
      grades[actualSize++] = atoi(p); // convert to number
    }
  }
  return actualSize;
}
```

Regarding the switch it could be rewritten as

```
for (int i = 0; i < gradeArraySize; ++i)
{
  freq[ grades[i] - 1 ]++;
}
```

if grades are 1-10 and freq is declared as `int freq[10] = {0};`

**EDIT2**

If you want to return an array from a function you can do it in a couple of ways.

The easiest but least effecient way is to return a copy of the array:

```
typedef struct
{
  int grades[100];
} returnarray;

returnarray foo()
{
  returnarray ar;
  ar.grades[0] = 42;
  ...
  return ar;
}
```

or more effectively

```
int foo(int **array)
{
  ...
  size_t size = 10;
  *array = malloc( size * sizeof(int) ); // changing what array points to
  ...
  *array[0] = 42; // assigning an int in the array
  ...

  return size; 
}
```

**EDIT3**

To return an array with a dynamic size you could write like this

```
char** getLines()
{
   const int maxLineLength = 32;
   char** lines = malloc( 11 * sizeof(char*) ); // note the extra pointer 10+1
   for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
   {
     lines[i] = malloc( maxLineLength );
     strcpy( lines + i, "hello" );
   }
   lines[10] = NULL;
   return lines;
}
```

caller

```
char** lines = getLines();

for (int i = 0; lines[i] != NULL; ++i)
{
  puts( lines[i] );
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Still pretty new to pointers. Im running gdb as of now... any other suggestions?

Comment: Thats actually pretty clever. Im still getting used to C..
Thank you so much. Will make the changes and hope it works.. I have a doubt though
Say i have a pointer *p that is storing the value of a function call say for example add(); but the return value is an array. How does it work then?
I mean if I have to edit the returning values.. or is there a better way to approach this?
Sorry for bothering so much..

Comment: @Ridhay I am not quite sure i understand what you mean, could you elaborate? If you want to return an array from a function there are a couple of ways you can do that. If you put the array in a struct then a copy will be returned to the caller. More effectively is to allocate memory on the heap and return the address of that memory. An array and a memory block can be treated pretty much in the same way in C.

Comment: I mean like say you have a function that returns an array x.
The function call is stored at a pointer. *p = fnc(); Something like that. Because I was going over my notes and thats how it was done there...
Also when you say "struct" what exactly do you mean?
What type of structure would that be? We haven't reached that far in C yet..
Thank you so much for being patient and helpful.

Comment: @Ridhay For `struct` see my edited answer. p = fnc() You can return an array like that but the problem is you cannot see the size of the array from that. You would need something like `p = fnc(&size);` so that fnc can tell the caller how large the array is that is returned (or some marker inside the array that tells that here is the end). The array returned should be stored on the heap (malloc) in order to make the address of the array known outside the function.

Comment: Thats extremely helpful!
Im still working on fixing this program. 
There is 3 of them in total..

Could I get your Email? There is one thing i need your help with.. I don't wanna create another post and I can't chat yet.. Of course if you are okay with it. If not i understand. youve helped me a lot! Thank you so so much!